# I want to add values from diffrent colums

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called leave:

```
leave_id    employee_id dateApplied leaveStrtDate   leaveEndDate    no_of_days  
3              1              2012-10-31    2012-10-10  2012-10-17        5     
4              1              2012-10-31    2012-10-24  2012-10-17       10
```

Now I want to add values from no_of_days column using mysql query, for eg.: the sum of no_of_days shoud be 15. Is there a way to do it in mysql query?

Comment: then what will happen to the record on columns: `dateApplied` ,`leaveStrtDate`,   `leaveEndDate`?

Comment: Have a look at the [SUM-function](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php)

Comment: @JohnWoo they will remain the same i just want to add no of days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select SUM(no_of_days) from leave;
```

[Document for sum ()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  employeeID, sum(no_of_days)  totalDays
FROM    leave
GROUP BY employeeID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(no_of_days) from leave
```

Comment: Isn't a where clause missing? Perhaps the OP wants the sum for a particular employee only.

Comment: Well maybe. OP did not say that.

Comment: It's just an assumption. Maybe OP wants to count the number of leaves of an employee whose ID is 1. It doesn't matter though. I'm not saying that the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(no_of_days) FROM leave;
```

You can use mysql sum function

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(no_of_days) from leave group by employee_id;
```

This will get total no of days of leave for each employee in the leave table.